# jQuery slider widget similar to cnet.com

Tags: plugins, widgets, jquery

I'm building a WP theme that requires a splash graphic "slider" widget (similar to what you see on cnet.com).

I'd like to build one myself, mainly so I can have full control over the bits, but if there are any available with licensing options for inclusion in commercial shipping software, I'd consider those as well.

Does anyone have an example they could share of creating a "graphic slider" widget (or plugin) using the built in WP jQuery script via enqueue?

By "graphic slider" I just mean a script that displays a series of named images, along with an index at the bottom that shows the current slide and allows tracking back/forward and to specific slides in the rotation.

It would be a bonus, if the widget had a control panel to allow the user to upload/delete each slider graphic as well as define the target URL for each image in a user friendly GUI with upload capability.

Thanks in advance for the help. Hope the question is not too conceptual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use a plugin, Take a look at the Smooth Slider plugin.  It is very good with the ability to add content and/or photos. You can reorder them, and it allows you to use custom post types, pages or posts. It has a lot of customization and using your owns stylesheet you can style it quite well.

You can see two different uses of my sites here. Www.nrined,com and www.wcpowersolutions.com

Another great one is a premium one from codecanyon.net it's called uBillboard.

Good luck, Larry

Comment: Thanks. I'm checking it out now. I could not resolve your first site www.nrined.com, but the 2nd one looks good. Thanks for sharing that. +1

Comment: Sorry, nrimed.com.  Still not used to iPad's keyboard.

Comment: Like the looks of those. I downloaded them to check them out. They might be a bit more robust than what I need, so I'm going to keep looking to find something a bit more tidy. Ideally I'd like a widget that could be drag/dropped into my header sidebar widget, then easily configured with a tabbed interface for each slide (title, text, image, link)